# A better solution for placing my 'logon' div on my page

Tags: html, css

I have a page where I divided things like this:

- a div for the header
- a div for the menu
- a div for the content

  - a div for the logon
- a div for the sidebar

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/f9eYx/3/

You noticed that the logon div is located inside of the content page. This is because I need the logon to be exactly on top of the content area. You noticed also that the sidebar can disappear with the Hide me hyperlink.

I don't like the logon inside of the content area. Is there any other solution? Possible to have the logon div at the same level as other div? I'm not very good at css and I'm pretty sure there is a better alternative for the logon placement.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you write. What do you mean?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish. You want to put your login visibly somewhere else or you want it where it is, but just not have the markup for it inside the content div?

Comment: I want to adjust the code to have a better approach for the placement of the logon hyperlink top right (just next to the sidebar). I don't want to code the showing of the logon dialog this is not the object of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a few of things.

First I don't have a problem with how you have the login button placed. I think it's fine, and it's probably where most people would look for it.

Secondly, you have a way to hide the sidebar, but no way to show it again. You should probably change that to a .toggle() function so you can see the side bar again at some point.

Third, I wouldn't use the line breaks in your main nav. You should use an unordered list and create each menu item as a list item.

As Tim suggested in his comment, you could create a cool login modal window, or have a login form slide down from the top. That would be pretty sweet.

But overall, the answer to your question is "I think where you have it is fine."

**EDIT**

One problem you're going to have is that this content is going to stretch as far as the width of the browser window. IF you have a really big screen it's going to look terrible. I would recommend wrapping your content in a "wrapper" div and give it a specific size, say 960px or 1000px.

If you used the wrapper div, you could put your login button inside the wrapper.

Ultimately, there are hundreds of ways to layout this code, and if you're positioning everything absolutely (not always the best option) it doesn't really matter where you place it in page, because they'll *almost* always end up in the same spot (depending on if it's parents are positioned absolute/relative.

**EDIT**

Ok, I set up this jsfiddle. It's not really perfect, but this is how I would do it. Or something similar. It obviously needs a ton of work and it's not very pretty, but it's a start.

http://jsfiddle.net/GvSSb/1/

Do you have a photoshop mockup of what you're trying to achieve? You should really go off of that, because if you just start typing in code it's probably not going to be as well thought out as it would if you had a visual guide to go off.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, for the toggle of the sidebar, I agree and it is the next step in my work :) for the navbar and linebreaks I also agree and this jsfiddle is only here for a sample. Finally for the logon modal window, I already have a page dedicated for the logon. For the placement of the logon hyperlink what I don't really like is the way I placed it with a negative top position. It seems (to me) not very nice. Don't you think? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Effectively, everything is positioned absolutely but I suck with CSS. Someone else gives me this solution. Other people voted for his answer so I concluded this answer may be a good one. About the wrapper (1000px) I personnally prefer a full width page but maybe I can set a max-width to something like 1500px for the big big screen?

Comment: added that jsfiddle. Check it out. There are a thousand ways to achieve what you want. I don't know about that position fixed thing you're doing. Personally, I don't like fixing things to the right or left, because you really don't have much control on how the site will look on various screen sizes and browser widths. But that's my opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a good start for me. Good work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float: right` property and adjust the `margin-right`, see : http://jsfiddle.net/f9eYx/6/.

```
div#logon {
    font-size: small;
    color: Black;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 260px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
```

When `[hide]` is clicked, use JavaScript or jQuery to reset the `margin-right`:

```
$('div#hideme').click(function(){
    $('div#logon').css('margin-right', '10px'); 
});
```

Comment: Hi GG, thanks for your response but I don't really like to have to reset the margin-right in jQuery...

Comment: You can't do what you ask without JavaScrip or jQuery.